# How to return multiple occurences with regex in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string with some blocks like this:

```
 Entity: ent
 Architecture: arch
 Library: path/to/my/lib0
 File: path/to/my/file.txt
 Instances: 1

 Package: pname
 Library: path/to/my/other/lib1
 File: path/to/my/other/file.txt
 Instances: 2

 Entity: another-ent
 Architecture: arch2
 Library: path/to/my/other/lib2
 File: path/to/my/other/file.txt
 Instances: 1
```

Now I want to get every value of Library (not only for this block) in tcl. But only when "Entity" is part of this block too (two lines above).
I want to have a procedure that returns me a list of all libraries, but only when "Entity" is mentioned before.
Fot this example I want the procedure to return

```
lib0 lib2
```

My approach:

```
regexp {.*Entity: *.*Library: .*/([^/\.]*)Source} $report -> all_libs
```

The problem: It only returns one occurence.

I'm also trying to get the "type". I.e is it an architecture, an entity or a file? For example `get_type ent` should return `Entity`. `get_type arch` should return `Architecture`.

My approach:

```
proc get_type { name } {
  set report " .... " # some blocks, defined above
  regexp ".* ( .*): $name" $report -> type
  echo "type: $type"
  return $type
}
```

But this only works for a few types, not all of them. Especially when I'm calling the proc with a string that is in the path like "`path`" in this example. It returns "`File`" but shouldn't. Only for "`file`" I want to get back `File`.

a call like `get_type ent` should return `Entity` and `get_type arch2` should return `Architecture`.
I'm not sure if my goal can be achieved easier without regular expressions.

Comment: Does `$report` contain the complete contents (all the blocks) or just one block? How are the blocks separated?

Comment: Could you give some concrete examples of blocks and what you would like to get as results? From what you said, it sounds like you want to get back the strings "path/to/my/lib" and "Entity" (doesn't sound like it can be all three since you mentioned 'architecture, entity **or** file').

Answer (score 2):

You will want the `-inline` and `-all` options to `regexp` (http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/regexp.htm). Without knowing more about your data, I can't help you craft your regex.

Comment: Perhaps `-indices` as well.